# Links for [tag:tag] works, but tag colouring doesn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

Here on Meta SE...

If you type `[meta-tag:status-completed]`, it correctly displays (in red) as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

However, if you use `[tag:status-completed]`, this correctly links to [the meta site's tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed) (the same as above), but it displays in the standard colour instead: [image].

Can we fix the tag colouring here?

Or would this be difficult to do?

Comment: It only links back here because there is no "main" site to link it to. I think it'd be a better idea to just disable the \[tag:\] syntax on this particular site and only allow \[meta-tag:\] syntax here - allowing users to mix them around on omly one site in the network would be confusing, and disabling it would encourage users to **link to the actual tag on whatever site** if they mention a tag on some other site, rather than relying on a broken syntax.

Comment: @animuson That would be fine too, I more have a problem with the inconsistent colouring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix for MSE magic tag preview & rendering is rolling out in build rev `2014.5.5.2211`. Note that existing posts won't be affected until edited though.